# Convert ~exists to forall in hypothesis

Tags: coq

I'm stuck in situation where I have hypothesis `~ (exists k, k <= n+1 /\ f k = f (n+2))` and wish to convert it into equivalent (I hope so) hypothesis `forall k, k <= n+1 -> f k <> f (n+2)`.

Here is little example:

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.Classical_Pred_Type.
Require Import Omega.

Section x.
  Variable n : nat.
  Variable f : nat -> nat.
  Hypothesis Hf : forall i, f i <= n+1.
  Variable i : nat.
  Hypothesis Hi : i <= n+1.
  Hypothesis Hfi: f i = n+1.
  Hypothesis H_nex : ~ (exists k, k <= n+1 /\ f k = f (n+2)).
  Goal (f (n+2) <= n).
```

I tried to use `not_ex_all_not` from `Coq.Logic.Classical_Pred_Type`.

```
Check not_ex_all_not.
not_ex_all_not
     : forall (U : Type) (P : U -> Prop),
       ~ (exists n : U, P n) -> forall n : U, ~ P n

apply not_ex_all_not in H_nex.
Error: Unable to find an instance for the variable n.
```

I don't understand what this error means, so as a random guess I tried this:

```
apply not_ex_all_not with (n := n) in H_nex.
```

It succeeds but `H_nex` is complete nonsense now:

```
H_nex : ~ (n <= n+1 /\ f n = f (n + 2))
```

On the other hand it is easy to solve my goal if `H_nex` is expressed as `forall`:

```
  Hypothesis H_nex : forall k, k <= n+1 -> f k <> f (n+2).
  specialize (H_nex i).
  specialize (Hf (n+2)).
  omega.
```

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644359/coq-convert-non-exist-to-forall-statement) but failed to apply it to my case.

Comment: I assume you mistyped `Hf` or something. Because it trivially proves your goal! :)

Comment: The error about ``n`` means that Coq didn't manage to guess the correct input of ``not_ex_all_not``. You would have to help by providing the term you want to use (your random guess is fine).

Comment: @Ptival, you are right, I tried to make my example more readable by dropping some `(+1)`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `not_ex_all_not` lemma, what you want to proof needs to look like the lemma. E.g. you can proof the following first:

```
Lemma lma {n:nat} {f:nat->nat} : ~ (exists k, k <= n /\ f k = f (n+1)) -> 
                                 forall k, ~(k <= n /\ f k = f (n+1)).
  intro H.
  apply not_ex_all_not.
  trivial.
Qed.
```

and then proof the rest:

```
Theorem thm (n:nat) (f:nat->nat) : ~ (exists k, k <= n /\ f k = f (n+1)) -> 
                                  forall k, k <= n -> f k <> f (n+1).
  intro P.
  specialize (lma P). intro Q.
  intro k.
  specialize (Q k).
  tauto.
Qed.
```

Comment: I accept this because it explains why I was not able to use `not_ex_all_not` directly. The question remains why it is defined in such a way but not as `lma`.

Comment: Btw, I think `specialize (lma P). intro Q.` is the same as `assert (Q := lma P).`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is.

Here is how to show trivially that your implication holds.

```
Section S.

  Variable n : nat.
  Variable f : nat -> nat.
  Hypothesis H : ~ (exists k, k <= n /\ f k = f (n+1)).
  Goal forall k, k <= n -> f k <> f (n+1).
  Proof.
    intros k H1 H2.
    apply H.
    exists k.
    split; assumption.
  Qed.

End S.
```

Also your goal is provable by `apply Hf.`, so I'm not sure but you seem to have some confusion...

Comment: Thank you very much. I see that it is really easy to prove it without additional lemmas. But I accept another answer because it explains why I was not able to use `not_ex_all_not`.