# DeMorgan's law for quantifiers in Coq

Tags: coq, quantifiers, first-order-logic, demorgans-law

I am trying to prove some FOL equivalences. I am having trouble using DeMorgan's laws for quantifiers, in particular

`~ (exists x. P(x)) <-> forall x. ~P(x)`

I tried applying not_ex_all_not from Coq.Logic.Classical_Pred_Type., and scoured StackOverflow ([Coq convert non exist to forall statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644359/coq-convert-non-exist-to-forall-statement), [Convert ~exists to forall in hypothesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558208/convert-exists-to-forall-in-hypothesis)) but neither came close to solving the issue.

```
Theorem t3: forall (T: Type), forall p q: T -> Prop, forall r: T -> T -> Prop, 
~(exists (x: T), ((p x) /\ (exists (y: T), ((q y) /\ ~(r x y)))))
<-> forall (x y: T), ((p x) -> (((q y) -> (r x y)))).
Proof.
intros T p q r.
split.
- intros H.
apply not_ex_all_not.
```

I get this error:

```
In environment
T : Type
p, q : T → Prop
r : T → T → Prop
H : ¬ (∃ x : T, p x ∧ (∃ y : T, q y ∧ ¬ r x y))
Unable to unify
 "∀ (U : Type) (P : U → Prop), ¬ (∃ n : U, P n) → ∀ n : U, ¬ P n"
with "∀ x y : T, p x → q y → r x y".
```

I expected DeMorgan's law to be applied to the goal resulting in a negated existential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's observe what we can derive from `H`:

```
~ (exists x : T, p x /\ (exists y : T, q y /\ ~ r x y))
=> (not exists <-> forall not)
forall x : T, ~ (p x /\ (exists y : T, q y /\ ~ r x y))
=> (not (A and B) <-> A implies not B)
forall x : T, p x -> ~ (exists y : T, q y /\ ~ r x y)
=>
forall x : T, p x -> forall y : T, ~ (q y /\ ~ r x y)
=>
forall x : T, p x -> forall y : T, q y -> ~ (~ r x y)
```

We end up with a double negation on the conclusion. If you don't mind using a classical axiom, we can apply [`NNPP`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.Classical_Prop.html) to strip it and we're done.

Here is the equivalent Coq proof:

```
Require Import Classical.

(* I couldn't find this lemma in the stdlib, so here is a quick proof. *)
Lemma not_and_impl_not : forall P Q : Prop, ~ (P /\ Q) <-> (P -> ~ Q).
Proof. tauto. Qed.

Theorem t3: forall (T: Type), forall p q: T -> Prop, forall r: T -> T -> Prop, 
~(exists (x: T), ((p x) /\ (exists (y: T), ((q y) /\ ~(r x y)))))
<-> forall (x y: T), ((p x) -> (((q y) -> (r x y)))).
Proof.
intros T p q r.
split.
- intros H x y Hp Hq.
  apply not_ex_all_not with (n := x) in H.
  apply (not_and_impl_not (p x)) in H; try assumption.
  apply not_ex_all_not with (n := y) in H.
  apply (not_and_impl_not (q y)) in H; try assumption.
  apply NNPP in H. assumption.
```

The above was a forward reasoning. If you want backwards (by applying lemmas to the goal instead of hypotheses), things get a little harder, because **you need to build the exact forms before you can apply the lemmas to the goal**. This is also why your `apply` fails. Coq doesn't automatically find where and how to apply the lemma out of the box.

(And `apply` is a relatively low-level tactic. There *is* [an advanced Coq feature](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html#rewriting-under-binders) that allows to apply a propositional lemma to subterms.)

```
Require Import Classical.

Lemma not_and_impl_not : forall P Q : Prop, ~ (P /\ Q) <-> (P -> ~ Q).
Proof. tauto. Qed.

Theorem t3: forall (T: Type), forall p q: T -> Prop, forall r: T -> T -> Prop, 
~(exists (x: T), ((p x) /\ (exists (y: T), ((q y) /\ ~(r x y)))))
<-> forall (x y: T), ((p x) -> (((q y) -> (r x y)))).
Proof.
intros T p q r.
split.
- intros H x y Hp Hq.
  apply NNPP. revert dependent Hq. apply not_and_impl_not.
  revert dependent y. apply not_ex_all_not.
  revert dependent Hp. apply not_and_impl_not.
  revert dependent x. apply not_ex_all_not. apply H.
```

Actually, there is an automation tactic called `firstorder`, which (as you guessed) solves first-order intuitionistic logic. Note that `NNPP` is still needed since `firstorder` doesn't handle classical logic.

```
Theorem t3: forall (T: Type), forall p q: T -> Prop, forall r: T -> T -> Prop, 
~(exists (x: T), ((p x) /\ (exists (y: T), ((q y) /\ ~(r x y)))))
<-> forall (x y: T), ((p x) -> (((q y) -> (r x y)))).
Proof.
intros T p q r.
split.
- intros H x y Hp Hq. apply NNPP. firstorder.
- firstorder. Qed.
```